# implementing https in MERN stack

Tags: https, mern, implementation

I am trying to find sources on implementing https in MERN stack without any additonal technologies, just by changing some codes of the given stack like changing http from tutorials to https. I do not know if it is possible.

I found different ways like buying the SSL cert. or applying another technology, still didnt find what I wanted around the internet. This is for some capstone project and I wanted to have the least technology to learn because I will do learn and code both at the same time.